# show a single item of an array that is passed from express to ejs template with next button to toggle single item

Tags: javascript, express, ejs

Here I have defined a route that finds all the items inside the question array, this array is then passed to the ejs template, the problem here is I want to render a single item on ejs page, not all items, with a next button, this button should toggle the next single item
[I have included a screenshot of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pGVTn.png)

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    email: String,
    password: String,
    question: []
});
```

```
app.get('/game', (req, res) => {    
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) { 
        const userId = req.user; //  iD is provided by passport.js
        User.find({ _id: userId }, (err, foundUser) => {
            foundUser.forEach((user) => {

                res.render('game', { questions: user.question }); //here questions is passed as an array variable to the ejs template
            });

        });

    } else {
        res.render('login');
    }
});
```

```
<%-include('partials/header')%>

    <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1 class="display-4">

            <%= questions%>// this will render 

        </h1>

        <hr class="my-4">
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" name="btn" value="">Previous</button>
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" name="btn" value="">Next</button>

        </p>
    </div>

<%-include('partials/footer')%>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to paginate your data using MongoDB using the query limits and page like this.

You can configure your limit to any but leave it at one if you wish to paginate it.
In other words, you can control your pages and limits using queries in your URL like this .
`localhost:3000/posts?page=1&limit=6` 
This will bring out six posts from the database .
Here's your solution

```
app.get('/game', (req, res) => {    
const { page = 1, limit = 1} = req.query
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) { 
        const userId = req.user; //  iD is provided by passport.js
       const users = User.find({ _id: userId   }).limit(limit * 1).skip((page - 1) * limit )

res.render('game', { questions: users.question })
    } else {
        res.render('login');
    }
}
```